# Pull correct JSON file in swift if cell selected

Tags: json, swift, segue

I have two JSON files: sports_week_1.json and sports_week_2.json
I have two static cells in my viewController, if the user taps index 0 I want to load sports_week_1.json, if they tap index 1 I want to load sports_week_2. I created a prepare for segue, but I am still getting errors. I am very new to swift.

//  ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class WeeksTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var curIndex: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailView = segue.destination as! LeaguesTableViewController
        curIndex = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!.row
        detailView.curIndex = curIndex

        let sportsFileName = (curIndex == 0) ? "sports_week_1" : "sports_week_2"
        if let file = Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self).path(forResource: sportsFileName, ofType: "json")


    }

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Expected '{' after 'if' condition

Comment: you are using a if let statement so you have to use the {}, change to this if let file = Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self).path(forResource: sportsFileName, ofType: "json"){}, so inside the {} you can use the constant file to do what you want

Comment: the constant files are:
        let sportsFileName = (curIndex == 0) ? "sports_week_1" : "sports_week_2"

Comment: then I placed sportsFileName
        if let file = Bundle(for: AppDelegate.self).path(forResource: sportsFileName, ofType: "json")

Comment: when you use if let statement you create a new constante, so inside the brackets you can use the constante file to do what you want